# How to weight the answers of a quiz so that two equal answers is impossible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am coding a personality test for a website and currently I'm struggling with how to weight answers, such that someone wouldn't be able to get two results with the same 'score'.

There are seven questions, each with six answers - one for each result. What weights do I need to give them such that a user cannot get two equally scored results?

Suppose the questions are equally weighted. If they answer three questions linked to result 1, 3 linked to result 2, and 1 to result 3, results 1 and 2 will have an equal score.

Comment: Do the weights have to be integers? Is there a size restriction?

Answer (score 3):

Let the $n$th question have weight $2^{n-1}$, for $n$ from $1$ to $7$. Here is a quick proof that no two of the results can have the same score:

Suppose the results are $R_1,R_2,...,R_6$. Now compare any two of the results $R_i$ and $R_j$, assuming that neither is $0$. They can be expressed as
$$R_i=2^{a_1}+...+2^{a_s}$$
$$R_j=2^{b_1}+...+2^{b_t}$$
Such that, for each $i,j$, $a_i \ne b_j$ (since the score from one question cannot be given to two different results), and such that $a_{i+1} \gt a_i$ and $b_{j+1} \gt b_j$. Then we have that the highest power of two dividing $R_i$ is $2^{a_1}$, and the highest power of $2$ dividing $R_j$ is $2^{b_1}$. But since $a_1 \ne b_1$, $R_i\ne R_j$. QED.

Unfortunately, if you use powers of two, only one of the questions will determine the outcome of the whole test (since $2^0+2^1+...+2^n=2^{n+1}-1$) but if you change $2$ to something like $1.5$ or $1.1$, the result holds, but there is no single question that determines the outcome of the entire test.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally, if you have $N$ total questions, use a weight of $c+2^{n-1}$ for the $n$th question, with $c \geq 2^{N}$ so that the weights will never cause a result with less responses to overtake one with more (since the added powers of two sum to $2^{N}-1$). The total of these weights would then be $Nc + 2^{N}-1$.
To then obtain the number of times that answer was chosen, you can divide the score by $c$ and floor.

To see why this results in totally unique scores, for each answer, you can assign a binary number representing the questions for which that answer was chosen; each bit corresponds to a question, and the bit is 1 if the question had that result and 0 if not. Since each question can only have one answer, the $n$th bit can only be set to 1 for one of the answers. The only way two answers can thus have the same score is if they're assigned the binary value 0 - i.e. neither was picked for any question. No amount of weighting the *questions* will change that - you can weight the answers, in the sense that you'll choose answer 1 over answer 2 in case of a tie, but in that case you don't need weights.

Comment: +1, this is equivalent to what I was about to suggest: give the questions equal weights and break ties by the first (in your case, last) question that distinguishes between them.